# Sort date without year pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I've a dataframe which contains 2 years of data. However, the columns do not contain the year attribute. Thus, I would like to know how can I sort the df in order to obtain new values at the end.

Below is the DF
date = day/month
weekday = {01:'monday',...}

```
date   weekday
01/01  06
01/01  07
02/01  07
02/01  01
03/01  01
03/01  02
.........
31/12  05
31/12  06
```

The ouput should look like below

```
date   weekday
01/01  06
02/01  07
03/01  01
.........
31/12  05
.........

01/01  07
02/01  01
03/01  02 
........
31/12  06
```

I was thinking of adding some random year (N and N+1) but I'm not really an expert on that.
Besides, I've tried the following code but it doesn't give the requested output

```
df.sort_values(by=['date', 'weekday'])
```

Thanks for anyone whose helping!

Comment: what is the priority in the sort? month ?

Comment: Just cast to datetime with `pd.to_datetime`, and then sort?

Comment: @sammywemmy it's month

Comment: @yatu but without the year, how can it be sorted?

Comment: By casting to datetime, a default year would be introduced. Give it a try :)

Comment: @yatu After applying to_datetime, here is the error OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 1-01-01 00:00:00.

Comment: Sometimes you need to help the parser so it knows what is what. So specify a format -> `df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.date, format='%m/%d')`

Comment: And then you just need `df.sort_values('date')`

Comment: @yatu it gives the same year for each date (1900). Thus, still the same order

Comment: So you need the years to increase? Then you need groupby.cumcount